# How do you replace an NC relay with a Schottky and transistors, or MOSFETs?

Tags: switches, relay, pnp

I'm a beginner and am trying to build a simple power control circuit.

The load of the circuit is the coil of a relay. Nothing else. According to the [datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2626622.pdf) it has 70 ohm internal resistance, but I measure 110K when it's off.

The current through the load is about 300 mA at the start and then drops to less than 1 mA. As this circuit is part of a larger one, the load HAS TO be placed after the "switch". So we need a high side switch.

The objective is to supply energy to this coil under normal conditions, unless a microcontroller commands a HIGH logic pulse (+3.3V).

Therefore, I could quite simply use another small relay and drive it directly from the microcontroller, but I'm looking to replace this second relay with solid state components.

I read about using a Schottky diode like in the following diagram, but this doesn't work. Probably the microcontroller is not supplying a high enough voltage to saturate the diode. Is there a way to boost that pulse from the microcontroller? Maybe by triggering a capacitor discharge?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Cd5x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I also tried with a PNP BJT transistor ([SS8550](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ss8550-d.pdf)) but I'm not quite clear on how it works. In my understanding, it will act as a closed switch when the base is pulled lower than the collector. So, while the load resistance is so little, I tried to ground the base directly. The transistor worked as intended, but got toasty in a matter of seconds. Then I tried to progressively increase the resistance on the base, and to my surprise it still worked with a 46 Kohm resistor! (but not with a 510 Kohm one). Why?

But even using such a large resistor between base and ground, the microcontroller is unable to pull up the base of the resistor and cut it off. So, how can we make it work?
Note that applying 5V to the base does work.
EDIT: do I have to add another transistor to act as an amplifier to switch the first one?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiJ4vp.png)</sup>

Comment: "the microcontroller is unable to pull up the base of the resistor and cut it off" because you most likely already fried that pin when you tried to power relay directly.

Comment: I didn't actually try that, as I don't have a 3.3v relay at hand. Anyway I can measure 3.3 V on the pin when pulled HIGH. I just tried to use a different pin, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Valentino:  [MOSFETs are transistors.  MOSFET = metal–oxide–semiconductor field-effect transistor. ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET) The things you are just calling "transistors" are in fact [bipolar junction transistors (BJT.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the JBT SS8550 with a [FQP27P06](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fqp27p06-d.pdf) MOSFET works. Using Darlington chain of 2 PNP BJTs also works. I'm choosing the latter solution:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSHChU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I now understand that the microcontroller couldn't cut off the PNP BJT because 3.3V is still more negative than a 0.6-0.7V drop from 5V. So there was still a negative bias strong enough between emitter and base that transistor continued to work. I had to bring down that emitter voltage for the microcontroller to have a chance. Therefore daisy chaining the transistors and using an appropriate resistor works a charm.

Thank you for correcting my grammar and improper naming, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a SPDT relay, you could just connect your load to the NC terminal and have the microcontroller turn the relay on, which would open the circuit.  That would mean that your relay is powered whenever the load is off, which might not be optimal for other reasons but we'd need to know more about the application.  Your transistor got hot without the base resistor because you were dumping a lot of current through the emitter-base junction.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAKKoD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: hi, thank you for for the suggestion but unfortunately that's not an option. Here's the complete circuit if you're curious: https://ufile.io/octstfa5 There probably are other issues with it, but I wanted to tackle this one first

Comment: Don’t give us links to dodgy download sites.

Comment: it's not that bad. Anyway, there's a mistake in the diagram. I'll reupload tonight.